# Windows server something takes up my drive space

Tags: windows, raid, hard-drive

I've been trying to figure this out but I really cannot understand.
I have two 1 TB hard drives with raid 1 and I have only 500 GB free space.
But I do not have any files that take up that much space.
I ran WinDirStat but I'm using only 44 GB

[WinDirStat and current usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lSBo.jpg)

I checked the shadow copies and I don't have any

[Shadow Copies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/988xi.png)

Can someone tell me how to free up this space?

Comment: Have you checked into "System Protection" -> https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/hard-drive-space-is-missing.html ?

Comment: Please enlighten us as to the specific release of Windows Server you are asking about.

Comment: Just  out of curiosity,  how much RAM does the server have?  What is the size of your page file and so on?  See the output of `Get-ChildItem C:\ -Force`  Also, are you running WinDirStat with administrative privileges?  If you account doesn't have access to the files, it cannot count them.

Comment: Thank you Zoredache! You are right! WinDirStat has to run with administrative privileges and I did not run with administrative privileges. Now it identifies where it takes up all the spaces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Zoredache! It has to run with administrative privileges. I ran WinDirStat with administrative privileges and found where it takes up the space.